# ROS Answers SE migration: GPS in EKF

Tags: navigation, ekf, gps, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using hector GPS in my robot.
I followed the instructions to introduce it in the EKF (robot_pose_ekf). However, the estimated pose is much worse taking the gps into account than that obtained ignoring it.

I think that the problem comes from de gps I am using because when I move the robot around it accumulates an error which never disappears. My GPS is Hector gps

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173713/gps-in-ekf/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Integration of GPS with robot_pose_ekf proved to be difficult for me when I tried it as well. Someone may have a good answer for you, but if it proves too difficult, I recently released the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package, which contains both an EKF localization node and a UTM transform node. The former can be used in place of robot_pose_ekf, and the latter allows for integration of GPS data. The [tutorials page](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials) contains a tutorial that details how to integrate a GPS sensor.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-06-18**:
I have taken a look to it and I thinks it is great. I received an error which I couldn't identify

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-06-18**:
[ERROR] [1403082870.757635304, 20.409000000]: Odometry pose transform error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 20.409000000 but the latest data is at time 20.402000000, when looking up transform from frame [base_footprint] to frame [base_link]

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-06-18**:
Does that error happen repeatedly, or does it happen just once or twice and then stop? Which node is reporting the error?

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-06-27**:
Sorry about the delay, but I was working in another project these days.
The ekf_localization_node generates the error continously.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-06-28**:
Are all the messages originating on the same machine? At what rate is your base_link->base_footprint transform being broadcast?

Feel free to send me an e-mail (see my GitHub page). I may have to have a look at your bag file and then we can update this question when we figure out the issue.